# Compare two files with window criteria

Tags: python

I am new to python and I want to compare columns from two files in python but the values of two columns are completely different from each other. I need to keep the criteria that if column from the second file is within some window of the column from the first file then it needs to compile both the raw from both the files and print in the output file.

The files have over 10 million rows.

Here is an example.

File1

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

File2

```
0 2 1
1 4 2
2 4 5
3 7 1
```

If first columns of both the files are same then if 2 & 3 columns of the second file lie within the window of "+1/-1" of 2 & 3 column of the first file then only it should print the combined raw as below:

Output

```
0 1 2 2 1
2 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: Is it a typo, I am not seeing any 2nd or 3rd column of File2 within range of -1 to +1?

Comment: No it's not a typo but it should print the value of column 2 and 3 from file 2 when it is between +1 or -1 of column 2 and 3 of file 1. So +1 and -1 show the range not the value.

Comment: `I want to compare columns from two files in python` - then tagging your question with `awk` is wasting our time so I'm going to remove it.

Comment: Sorry if I have wasted your time I am just looking for alternative too and that's why I kept awk but it's ok.

Comment: Guessing that "number of rows in crore" is a strange way of saying 10+ million rows, so now it's fixed. Please use terms that are understood also outside your country.

Comment: Thank you James Z